# How to extend Lifelog

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

Dose anyone knows (especially someone from sony) is it possible to add new activity to Lifelog like for example ice skating?

Additionally is it possible to add activities from external app? Like from custom ebook application we are sending REST call to Lifelog services with activity book reading.

Answer (score 0):

The Lifelog API is a read-only API. Unfortunately you will not be able to add new activities.

Comment: I've notice that ;-) but if you can add sich ability I could dramatically increase the usability and ability of creating new extensions/apps. Can you consider this in your road map? Lifelog is nice but we are not spending whole day in our mobile, additional app on desktops could be really nice.